# How do i stack QLabels on top of each other in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

I've been trying to find a way to stack QLabel images on top of each other in a VQboxLayout.
I want the images to be displayed on top of each other and a lite bit moved down for each image. Like a hand of cards so you can see all your cards you have.
Right now I'am storing all the label in an array:

QLabel *cards[10];

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QGraphicsScene best fits your needs. Make your QLabel(s) as QGraphicsPixmapItem (inherit QGraphicsItem) and `addItem`(s) to your scene. Best thing to do is to look at the QT doc examples.